# How to tie mysql database in one container to another container running my django blog app (with docker-compose)

Tags: mysql, django, docker, docker-compose, containers

I have created a blog app with django and attached it to a mysql database stored on my local machine(localhost), which I manage through phpmyadmin.

However, I switched to an ubuntu 18.04 LTS (previously on a windows machine) and wanted to deploy my app with docker containers. 
I want to run mysql database in one container, and my blog app in another container, and have them communicate with each other (I am using docker-compose to achieve this).

Below is the DATABASES dictionary on my app:

[image]

And here is docker-compose.yml file.

[image]

After firing the docker-compose up command, I get this error:

[image]

It says '(2006, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or diectory")'.

Comment: It's always better to provide your files as text, not as screenshot (not only on stack overflow). When people try to help you or explain you what to change in the answer, they have to transcribe from the image instead of simply copying.

Answer (score 1):

In the DB container, you are only setting password for `root` user but using `test` user. So you either need to set `MYSQL_PASSWORD` env var. Or use `root` user.

More on the env variables in [mysql docker hub docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)

My recommendation is to change db service definition to

```
services:
    db: 
        image: mysql
        enviroment: 
            MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
            MYSQL_DATABASE: test
            MYSQL_USER: test
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
```

This encurages not to use root user, which is considered best practice.

---

What actually probably causes this errors is that you have wrong version of mysql. On [mysql docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), you can see that the `latest` tag (with is the implicit tag if you don't provide any), is the same as `8.0`. But a lot of apps is only compatible with the older `5.7`. To switch this, in your docker-compose add `5.7` tag:

```
services:
    db: 
        image: mysql:5.7
```

(5.7 and 8.0 is actually only one major release apart, and 8.0 was released in 2017)